# Need to force display of figures and close as needed during running of code

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a python code that plots several figures.  The relevant parts are

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
for p in range(np):
    for g in range(ng):
        figs = []
        for n in range(ns):
            figs.append(plt.figure())
            gsg = # object I am working with
            cg = plt.contourf(gsg.x, gsg.y, gsg.u[:,:])
            cb = plt.colorbar()
            figs[n].suptitle(title)
            print title, gsg.u[ex_index,ex_index,:]
        go_ahead = raw_input()
```

For certain cases, I can't run this straight through and just look at all the figures because too many figures are produced and python starts automatically closing several of them.

So what I want is for that inner loop to plot `ns` figures, then I pause the execution (hence the `go_ahead` input), look at the displayed figures, close them on the screen, and let the code go to the next batch.  I can't figure out how to make this work.

The closest I have come is by putting `plt.show(block=True)` command after `figs[n].suptitle()`.  This does result in the display of a figure during run time, but I can only see one figure at a time.  `plt.show()` and `plt.show(block=False)` does not result in any display at all, until the end of execution, which is what I am trying to avoid.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to put `plt.show()` at the same indentation level as `go_ahead=` to show all the figures in the inner loop

Comment: @DavidG  Thanks.  That was an improvement.  However, now I can't close all of the figures.  One is always left open.  And it interferes with further plotting somehow.

Comment: Theres `plt.destroyAllWindows()` or whats its name?

Comment: Hmm, sounds strange... Is it possible to create some fake data so that we can repoduce the problem?